# Is there a help file for the bitcoin client?

Tags: client

Is there a help file / man page that explains all the possible commands and arguments for the bitcoin daemon?

I'm looking for an in-depth coverage of the commands seen when I do `bitcoind help`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Bitcoin Config Arguments](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin)
- [Bitcoin CLI Commands](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list)

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list is exactly what I was looking for - thank you!